# How to make a Dataflow job to use different worker pools for different stages of a workflow?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Is there a way to tie worker pool with a particular stage of a workflow?
I have a Dataflow workflow which has one stage that can be ran in parallel only inside one worker (it updates a specific file database, which supports parallel updates, but have to be stored locally). So for this particular stage I would like to use a worker with bigger amount of CPUs (n1-standard-64) while for all others I use n1-starndard-4.

Dataflow supports worker pools, where I can describe how many instances must be instantiated and which machineType must be used. Moreover I can specify multiple worker pools and java doc says:

> [Note that a workflow job may use multiple pools, in order to match the various computational requirements of the various stages of the job.](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/dataflow/v1b3/java/latest/com/google/api/services/dataflow/model/WorkerPool.html)

And Dataflow REST client [supports this and expects an array](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/reference/rest/v1b3/projects.jobs#environment) when you want to specify workerPools.

So the question is how to tie the stage with specific worker pool? Is there any way to do that?